# What is the .app folder? How can it be turned into a .dmg archive?

Tags: javascript, node.js, macos, electron

I am using `electron-packager` on Mac OS X Sierra. I can easily package my entire application, which creates a `release` folder. Within it, there is a folder called `<AppName>.app`, which I can open.

I wanted to make a `.dmg` to easily distribute it. However, this folder behaves in pretty mysterious ways. I went to Disk Utility, and selected new image from folder. When I go to select my `.app` folder, it somehow appears as a full application already. It doesn't appear as a folder.

I tried taring the folder.

```
tar -cvzf app.tar.gz MyApp.app
```

However, when I extract it in finder, it also turns out to be a whole, working application.

What is this strange behavior of the .app folder and how can it be distributed as an installable .dmg?

Answer (score 1):

Application on macOS are typically stored in an ["application bundle"](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000123i-CH101-SW1) (completely unrelated to Webpack/Browserify, by the way).

In Finder, and also in file dialogs, these appear to be single items. As you call it, a "full application". Under the hood, however, these items are really directories/folders. If you look at it from a lowerlevel point of view, say from Terminal, you'll see a directory called `MyApp.app`.

If you want to create a DMG from it, use the `release` folder that contains the application bundle. If there are other files there that you don't want to add to the DMG, either remove them, or create a new empty directory, move the app there, and use *that* as the folder to create the DMG from.